# CreateChannel() The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-core

Im trying to send simple request from my .net core console app to wcf service.

```
            Binding binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
            ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(url)));
            IService serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();
            var result = serviceProxy.GetDataUsingDataContract(new CompositeType()
            {
                BoolValue = true,
                StringValue = "TestString"
            });
            factory.Close();
```

And i got an error on `factory.CreateChannel()`:

> The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.
>   Parameter name: via'

I tried to pass BasicHttpsSecurityMode(Transport, TransportWithMessageCredential) param in BasicHttpsBinding - but got no result

How can i call WCF service from .net core console app using ChannelFactory?

Comment: What is your service endpoint address?  It seems that the service is publish over https. So specify a https Uri, try to add a callback validation (on client end).
Besides, you could add service reference to call the service by using Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference provider, it could auto generate the client proxy class. Before calling the service via client proxy class, we only need to modify the auto-generated configuration.